# htaccess - rule explanation

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering if anyone could explain what this rule is saying:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ news.php?name=$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It translates URLs like:

```
/foo.html
```

into URLs like:

```
/news.php?name=foo
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Match anything that ends with .html in the URL string.  Pass the file part before .html and after the domain name to the news.php script as $_GET['name'].

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I upvoted it, but picked the other answer as the accepted answer as it explained it a little easier.